# Does calling .WriteXml on an ADO.NET DataSet cause an implied .AcceptChanges()?

Tags: dataset

I have a small application that uses a dataset as a backingstore.  I want to provide some amount of recoverability in the event of a program crash without having to constantly update and save my master file.  If I were to call .WriteXml on my dataset to a "recovery" file, will that cause an implied "AcceptChanges" to be performed on my dataset?  If so, can I clone my master dataset to a new object and save it instead?

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: -1: it's pretty simple to try it and see - have you done that yet?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, no AcceptChanges will be called. But why don't you just check?